# DATABASE lacks a quorum of nodes for high availability

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, sql-server-2017, failover

Just after setting up successfully `alwayson` - availability group,
testing the failover,

I get this error message:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Failed to resume data movement in database 'APCORE', which resides on the availability replica 'MY_SERVER' in the availability group 'AG_TS'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=14.0.17289.0+((SSMS_Rel_17_4).181117-0805)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&LinkId=20476

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Unable to access database 'APCORE' because it lacks a quorum of nodes for high availability. Try the operation again later. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 988)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=14.00.1000&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=988&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

[image]

what I have is a [Quorum for 3 nodes AlwaysOn Availability Group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/154484/22336)

my windows server 2016 cluster has a quorum disk set up:

[image]

There is a related question here:

[Failover Cluster Instance work without quorum](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/99222/22336)

What does that message mean?

Comment: Is WSFC up and running ? And I believe you have `node and disk majority` as quorum

Comment: There seems to be quite a bit wrong with that setup. Why are there disks sitting in available storage if it's an FCI? Why was failover done at the AG level as the FCI takes precedence and removes the ability for automatic failover, etc. In terms of the quorum issue, it seems that you don't have it - what does the current node see in terms of other nodes?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the Windows Failover Cluster logs? Can you confirm system time is accurate on all nodes? Are your ports open (5022 by default) between all replicas? Synchronous or Asynchronous replicas?

Answer (score 0):

I have face same error for two instances and we re-booted secondary server services post that it started working fine and for second instance we removed DB from AG and deleted from secondary server and then added backup to AG using Autoseeding then it started working fine.